# Buttons mistake in discord.py

Tags: python, button, discord, discord.py

## So, I wanted to made a marry system on our server, but have got some mistakes in buttons:

```py
@client.tree.command(name='marry', description="Suggest to marry", )
async def marry(interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.Member):
    print(f'{interaction.user}||{user}')
    if interaction.user == user:
        await interaction.response.send_message(content=f"{interaction.user.mention} you can`t marry yourself :(")
        return
    else:
        embed_marry = discord.Embed(title='WOW.....', description=f'{interaction.user.mention} suggest a marry to {user.mention}', color=0x774dea)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed_marry, view=MarryButtons())


class MarryButtons(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    #Green button under merry_embed in "async def marry"
    @discord.ui.button(label="Yes", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success)
    async def agree_btn(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button, user: discord.Member):
        embed_agree = discord.Embed(title=f'{user.mention} answered YES', description=f'{user.mention} now married to {interaction.user.mention}')
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed_agree)

    # Red button under merry_embed in "async def marry"
    @discord.ui.button(label="No", style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger)
    async def disagree_btn(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button, user: discord.Member):
        embed_disagree = discord.Embed(title=f'{user.mention} answered NO', description=f'{user.mention} declined propose from {interaction.user.mention}')
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed_disagree)

    # Gray emoji button under merry_embed in "async def marry"
    @discord.ui.button(label="", style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def emoji_btn(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button, user: discord.Member):
        embed_emoji = discord.Embed(title=f'{user.mention} canceled propose', description=f'Nothing changed')
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed_emoji)
```

In general it looks good, but when I try to click them, there is an "interaction error" in discord.
I'm using discord.py 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With lack of knowledge about the error itself, the mistake I see is that you put a user variable in a button.

`async def agree_btn(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button, user: discord.Member):`

Remove the variable and the interaction will go through.

`async def agree_btn(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button:`

*Extra: you can get the user from the marry command. Set a global `user` variable and change the value of it with the command. Then you can access it int the button class. Second option would be database or json for mutiple request handle*